# Can my MSE reputation be any positive integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As far as I know there are five kinds of vote

- $+2$ for an edit
- $-2$ for a downvote
- $+10$ for an answer
- $+15$ for an accepted answer
- $+5$ for a question

Suppose that this is true. Can a MSE reputation take any positive integer value? How do you prove it?

Comment: You forgot the +100 association bonus. Furthermore, there is the +200 reputation cap which may cause you to get only a part of some reputation (edit, answer, accepted answer) score when you hit that cap.

Comment: if one downvotes something one gets -1.

Comment: No. The universe will experience a heat death, so time is finite, and hence the total number of possible MSE posts is finite. Your reputation cannot be any positive integer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Just note that one upvote on a question, and then two downvotes equal $1$ point in reputation.

(Also note that $+2$ for edits only hold below a certain limit; and you can lose a point by downvoting an answer.)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, since $\gcd(2,15)=1.$ Then use that $15-7(2)=1=15+7(-2)$ Multiply this by any $n$ to get $n$ points.